# Prevent route navigation under certain circumstances

Tags: angular

In vanilla JS, it's easy enough to stop a link from navigating, via `preventDefault()`. However, in Angular, it doesn't seem to be that easy and I'm not sure what the right solution is. For example, I have a top menu in which some items are dropdowns in some conditions and should open on click, and in others should behave as normal links. I did what I thought I would normally do:

```
toggleMenu(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Usual logic goes here
}
```

But this doesn't stop navigation, and I'm not sure how to stop it. I can make it much more complex by creating guards on every link with a service to stop it, but that definitely feels overkill. Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to stop a `routerLink`?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question, and there isn't a clear intention in the RouterLink source code that shows there is support for disabling the click handler.

If you assign `null` to the router link it will route to the current route. Which is basically the same as not changing the route, but I don't know if this still triggers a route change or not.

```
<a [routeLink]="condition ? '/my/route/address' : null">Link</a>
```

`condition` can be a template variable or you could call a component method if you need to calculate something more complex. The key is to yield `null` when you want to disable the link.

Comment: Thanks; I'll take a look if it triggers a route change.